# Why do these vectors not span the given space?

Tags: linear-algebra, span

[image]

I need some help understanding this solution to a problem. I am working on the problem above. I know that in order for a set of vectors to be a basis it must be linearly independent and span the given space. In the solution above it says that $v_1$ and $v_2$ will not be in the span for $H$. Doesn't the solution $0v_1+v_2+0v_3$ span $H$? Why does it say that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not in the span?

Comment: Could you tell us what $H$ is?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese $H$ is the set of vectors whose 2nd and 3rd entries are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what was meant is that $v_1$ and $v_3$ aren't in $H$.

As $v_1, v_3 \not\in H$ and $v_1, v_3 \in \operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, we see that $H \neq \operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, so $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is not a spanning set for $H$.

You claimed that $\{v_2\}$ spans $H$, but this is false as $(1, 0, 0) \in H$ but $(1, 0, 0) \notin \operatorname{span}\{v_2\}$. Even if $H$ were spanned by $v_2$, then as $v_2 \in \operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, we could only say that $H \subseteq \operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$.

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to why $H$ is not a span of the three vectors if $v_1$ and $v_3$ are not in $H$. Is this because the second and third entries in $v_1$ and $v_3$ are not equal? Or is it that when an element is not in $H$, then it can't span $H$?

Comment: You are correct on both counts. As the second and third components of $v_1$ are not equal, $v_1 \notin H$; likewise for $v_3$. However, $v_1 \in \operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ as $v_1 = 1v_1 + 0v_2 + 0v_3$; likewise for $v_3$. As there are elements of $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ which are not in $H$ (namely $v_1$ and $v_3$), the two sets are not equal. More generally, given a subspace $V$ and a finite set of vectors $\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$, a necessary (but not sufficient) condition that $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \dots, v_k\} = V$ is that $v_i \in V$ for $i = 1, \dots, k$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm not sure that $v_2$ spans H or that $H\subseteq span\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$; isn't (1,0,0) in H?

Comment: @user84413: You are correct. I was focused on explaining why $H \neq \operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, so I completely missed this. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelAlabanese Thanks - you gave a good explanation of the crux of the matter, that $H\ne span\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$.